# Convexity of an equivalent norm

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, norms

Let $X=l_2$ with usual norm $\|\cdot\|_2$. We define a subspace of $X$ as $D=conv (B_{l_2} \cup B),$ where $B = \{ (x_n) \in l_2 : \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{2} x_n^2 \leq 1\}$, conv is the convex combination and $B_{l_2}$ is the closed unit ball in $l_2$ with usual norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert_2$. We define Minkowski's functional on set $D$ by $$ \mu_D(x)=\inf \{ t > 0 : x \in tD \}.$$ Then $\Vert \cdot \Vert = \mu_D( \cdot )$ defines an equivalent norm on $(l_2, \Vert \cdot \Vert_2)$, where $\Vert \cdot \Vert_2$ is the usual norm on $l_2$. The norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ on $l_2$ is not rotund. Now, I take $$x, x_n \in S_{(l_2, \Vert \cdot \Vert)} \text{ with } \lim_{n \to \infty}\Vert x+x_n \Vert =2. \tag 1$$ I must show that $(x_n)$ has a weakly convergent subsequence converging to an elemnt in $A_0(x)$, $A_0(x)=\{y \in S_X : \Vert \frac{x+y}{2} \Vert =1 \}$. For Minkowski's functional to give a semi-norm, $D$ has to be an absorbing set. However, I do not understand how I can form the seminorm or proceed to prove that $(x_n)$ satisfying equation $(1)$ has a weakly convergent subsequence in $A_0(x)$. Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Since $\|\cdot\|$ and the usual norm of $\ell_2$ are equivalent, the sequence $(x_n)_n$ is bounded and hence has a weakly convergent subsequence by reflexivity of $\ell^2$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Sorry that I missed one statement. No doubt reflexivity gives a weakly convergent subsequence. But I need to check whether $(x_n)$ has a weakly convergent subsequence converging to an element in $A_0(x)$ or not.

Comment: What does $(B_{l_2} \cup B)$ mean? The same as $B_{l_2} \cup B$? If so, then $D$ is not convex and hence $\mu_D$ is not a norm.

Comment: @ Iosif Pinelis, I am sorry for the mistake.  D is the convex combination of elements from $(B_{l_2} \cup B)$.

Comment: I doubt very much that this is true because spheres in Banach or Hilbert spaces are usually not weakly closed. I would try to modify the standard example of the unit vectors $e_n$ in $\ell^2$ which belong to the sphere but converge weakly to $0$.

Comment: I think for element $e_n$ belongs to the set $A_0(x)$, $(e_n)$ will not have any weakly convergent subsequence and hence $A_0(x)$ will not be compact.